# Syntax transition between Vector to TreeMap (java)

Tags: java, vector, treemap

Would like to know how to translate all my logic from use of :

```
static List<ServerThread> s_PlayersOnServer = new Vector<ServerThread>();
```

To

```
 static Map s_PlayersOnServer = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap());
```

For example I have this sample:

```
ServerMain.s_PlayersOnServer.get(clientSerialNumber-1).setPlayerName(playerName);
```

And after I switched to Map implementation but the same logic doesn't work:

```
ServerMain.s_PlayersOnServer.get(clientSerialNumber).setPlayerName(playerName);
```

The function setPlayerName is not known in the new context and I don't know why
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your List is typed correctly whereas your Map isn't.

Consider

```
 static Map<Integer, ServerThread> s_PlayersOnServer = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<Integer, ServerThread>());
```

If the clientSerialNumber is indeed an integer.

Regards